# Strange cache of an output file

Tags: c#, caching, dll, replace, copy

I've got a specific problem in my C# solution. There are three projects: MainProgram, Install, FileBrowser (Output type: Class Library - DLL).

When I rebuild the FileBrowser, VS generates a new, up-to-date file FileBrowser.dll in the output directory, everything's OK.
But (here begins the problem), when I rebuild an entire solution, or even just one of the other projects (both require building FileBrowser first), FileBrowser.dll restores to the earlier version from 2015-04-11 4:54 PM. Exactly this datetime is in the file's "Last modified" property.

I really do not remember if that day I did something really "special" so VS cached the output file from then and now it still annoys me with its copies.

How can I fix this? Where this old file FileBrowser.dll could be stored? I did use a Windows search option (Win 7) but it seems that file must have another name in the cache.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

This should fix your problem:

1. Remove the reference of **FileBrowser.dll**
2. Add reference for **FileBrowser project**.

How did it happen?
Initially you were adding a reference to FileBrowser.dll, the ide cashed that dll in one of the directories of your solution and copying it to the output directory. what you really needed is a reference to the output of the FileBrowser Project which is again FileBrowser.dll - but a reference to the project so you can get the latest complied version each time you build the solution.

Comment: Did you really mean `FilBrowser.dll`?